# How to check the prime numbers from a vector in c++?

Tags: c++, function, vector

I have written a piece of code below, that asks for a user to input the number of a vector's elements and the elements of it. I want to use a function for checking prime numbers from the vector. For example, I have a vector with 2,6,3,7 as elements and the function have to check how many prime numbers are there, but the output shows that the vector has only 2 prime numbers. So, my question is: why is not my code working?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int input_vector(int a,int t[20]);
int output_vector(int a,int t[20]);
int prime(int a,int nr[20]);

int main()
{
    int i,n,m,v[20],w[20];
    
    cout<<"Enter the number of vector's elements:";
    cin>>n;
    input_vector(n,v); //input vector
   
    cout<<"The vector is: ";
    output_vector(n,v); //output vector
    cout<<endl;
    
    prime(n,v); //prime numbers from vector
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    
    
}

int input_vector(int a,int t[20])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        cout<<"v["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>t[i];
    }
}

int output_vector(int a,int t[20])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++) cout<<t[i]<<" ";
}

int prime(int a,int nr[20])
{
    int i,p,j;
    p=0;
    
    for(j=1;j<=a;j++)
        for(i=2;i<=(nr[j]/2);++i)
        {
            if((nr[j]%i==0)) p=p+1;
        }
    
    if(p!=0) cout<<"The vector has "<<p<<" prime numbers.";
    else cout<<"THERE ARE NO PRIME NUMBERS!";
    
}
```

Comment: Array indexes start at `0` not `1`.

Comment: Your `prime` function doesn't do what you think it does. I suggest stepping through it in a debugger to get a better idea of what the code is doing, and why that's wrong in a few different ways. Take special note of when `p` is incremented (it won't be incremented for `2`, `3` or `7`, but will be incremented twice for `6`).

Comment: _"can start at 1 too"_ `v[20]` creates an array with 20 elements with indices from 0 to 19. Starting the index with 1 means skipping the first element. Accessing `t[20]` goes out of bounds and causes undefined behavior, often a program crash.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I started the array with `1` because I put there `i<=a` and `j<=a`, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I noticed that the `p` will be incremented twice for `6` and maybe for other even numbers, but I can't figure it out how to make that function working.

Comment: @paokv *"can start at 1 too"* - No, they can't. If you access them like that you will access bad elements causing memory corruptions and all kinds of undefined behaviour.

Comment: As I said you are wasting one array element because you are skipping the first element. You are allocating memory for 20 elements but you can only use 19 of them. For some people this is already a problem. If you call the function with `a=20` you'll go out of bounds and cause undefined behavior which often leads to a program crash. That's a problem for most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the logic flow of your algorithm to find prime numbers.
I have fixed it down below, and also made your methods `void` as they don't return anything. Variables declared and not used where also eliminated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void input_vector(int a,int t[20]);
void output_vector(int a,int t[20]);
void prime(int a,int nr[20]);

int main()
{
    int n,v[20];

    cout<<"Enter the number of vector's elements (between 0 and 19):"; // see comments under OP question
    cin>>n;
    input_vector(n,v); //input vector

    cout<<"The vector is: ";
    output_vector(n,v); //output vector
    cout<<endl;

    prime(n,v); //prime numbers from vector
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}

void input_vector(int a,int t[20])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        cout<<"v["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>t[i];
    }
}

void output_vector(int a,int t[20])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++) cout<<t[i]<<" ";
}

// here algorithm to find prime numbers was faulty
void prime(int a,int nr[20])
{
    int i,p,j, counter;        // added a counter
    p=0;

    for(j=1;j<=a;j++) {
        counter = 0;
        if (nr[j] == 0 || nr[j] == 1)  // 0 and 1 are not counted as primes
            counter++;
        for(i=2;i<=(nr[j]/2);++i) {  // if a divisor of nr[j] is found, add 1 to counter
            if (nr[j]%i==0) {
                counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 0)          // if no divisors found, then +1 primes' count
            p += 1;
    }

    if(p!=0) cout<<"The vector has "<<p<<" prime numbers.";
    else cout<<"THERE ARE NO PRIME NUMBERS!";
}
```

### Edit

`0` and `1` now won't be counted as primes, as per OP's request.
Also added a `break` command as soon as one divisor is found, and added a warning not to input more than 19 numbers (limit imposed by the size of the array `v` inside the code).

Comment: Thanks, but I have one more question: how can I get `0` and `1` out of the prime numbers?

Comment: You mean if `v = {0,1}` for instance, you want the result to be `p = 0`, no prime numbers found?

Comment: Yes, I tried to put in both conditional instructions `(nr[j]==1)||(nr[j]==0)` or `!=` but it didn't work.

Comment: @paokv Done.. if you now find this answer more useful, please consider marking it as useful by clicking the upward arrow up next to the left of the answer, thanks

Comment: Thank you! Marked from the first!